# Ruby Inject keeps returning NilClass

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm running a simple SQL query to return a hash.
Although I can effortlessly do it with a .each method, I was hoping I could also do it with the .inject({}) method, but this method returns nil two third of the time.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is the .each method that works fine

```
  def self.availabilities(days=10)
    hash = {}
    where(
      'date >= ? AND date <= ?',
      Date.today, Date.today + days
    )
    .each do |availability|
      p availability
      if hash[availability.checker.display_name]
        hash[availability.checker.display_name] << availability.date
      else
        hash[availability.checker.display_name] = [availability.date]
      end
    end
    hash
  end
```

It returns a hash as expected

```
CheckerAvailability.availabilities(12)).to eql({
  'Clint Eastwood' => [Date.today, Date.today + 1.day],
  'Bob Morane' => [Date.today + 11.days]
}
```

This is the inject method

```
.inject({}) do |hash,elmt|
  p "hash ==> #{hash}"
  puts '------------------'
  if hash[elmt.checker.display_name]
    hash[elmt.checker.display_name] << elmt.date
    hash
  else
    hash[elmt.checker.display_name] = elmt.date
    hash
  end
end
```

The puts return

```
"hash ==> {}"
------------------
"hash ==> "
------------------
"hash ==> "
------------------
```

And if I try to iterate over it, of course it doesn't work.

Thanks anyone for your help

Have a great day !

Comment: Just a side note: It looks like your are running N+1 queries and your code's performance might improve a lot by using `include` or a database join. Is `checker` a default `belongs_to :checker` association and is `display_name` a column in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You abuse `inject` by producing redundant intermediate objects. Besides that you should handle element as a block parameter, you should use `each_with_object` instead of `inject`. Another glitch is that you should create an array when the respective hash element is missing, while you create a string.

```
.each_with_object({}) do |elem, hash|
  (hash[elmt.checker.display_name] ||= []) << elmt.date
end
```

Wrong in your code (besides incorrect block params):

```
hash[elmt.checker.display_name] = elmt.date
```

should be:

```
hash[elmt.checker.display_name] = [elmt.date]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I finally get it... Obviously I'm trying inject where i shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.inject({}) do |hash,elmt|
  p "hash ==> #{hash}"
  puts '------------------'
  if hash[elmt.checker.display_name]
    hash[elmt.checker.display_name] << elmt.date
    hash
  else
    hash[elmt.checker.display_name] = elmt.date
    hash
  end
end
```

you must refer to two arguments. First is your argument from inject, here your hash, and second is each element from your loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my original question, i did try with two arguments originally but it does not work still..

Comment: You are welcome to review my answer to see what is wrong here.